# Place Order Button is Disabled in B2B Commerce Checkout page after Winter 24 Release

Tags: digital-experience, b2b-commerce, lwr, b2b, place-order-button

We are setting a B2B commerce LWR digital experience site in the developer org. After winter 24 release, when we put "Place Order" button under Checkout Layout:
**Accordion -> Checkout Section -> Proceed -> Place Order Button, the button** is disabled.

Even after all the information in the checkout section the "Place Order Button" component (released in the Winter 24 release) doesn't become enabled.

**Just wanted to confirm, if anyone facing a similar problem in the LWR site's Checkout page (Place Order button component) after the Winter 24 release?**

Comment: The button is probably disabled because of some error. The new checkout layout needs "Checkout Notification" component to show the error message.  Can you publish the store with Checkout Notification component added and see if the error shows up?

Comment: Have you been able to try with the "Checkout Notification" component added?

Comment: Certainly, I am experiencing the same issue in my development organization. The "Place Order" button is disabled. Please let me if you receive a resolution.